# OO-design with casting / structure issue

Tags: java, oop, casting

I have a class which does operations on the database, but I want to keep it as general and abstract as possible, thus by Object return types.

Here's an example method of that class:

```
public static List<Object> getAll(String table) throws HibernateException{
        Session sessie = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction trans = sessie.beginTransaction();

        List<Object> objects = sessie.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + ";").list();
        trans.commit();
        sessie.close();
        return objects;
 }
```

Now I have another class `User` which should have a a method `getAll` with a `List<User>` return type and the implementation of the method is the same.

Is this even possible? I know it isn't possible to overload methods with different return types. Is this doable with some kind of a design pattern, interface setup?

So basicly I don't want to do the implementation again, it is already specified in the `getAll` method which returns an object. I just want to perform that method but with dynamic return types.

The reason I am asking this is because I don't want to do the following somewhere else in my code:

```
User user = new User(...);
// this should be user.getAll() and the type of that method should be an User, not an object
(User)user.getAll()
```

The reason I am doing it this way is because I can have other tables in the future whom would be able to call the `getAll` method but get a cast object back as return type and not the type object.

I am looking at the cleanest and best OO solution, even if it means that I need to restructure my code.

Comment: You mark your question as answered by ticking the "accept" tick symbol next to the answer, not by putting "SOLVED" in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need it you can make your class generic with returned type as generic type parameter, so you can have:

```
public static List<T> getAll(String table)
```

and then do

```
user = new YourGenericClass<User>();
List<User> list = user.getAll("user");
```

It's ugly though as you pass the name of the table as a parameter. You should probably rethink your data access layer design .

edit:

Ok to make it clearer:

```
//Template generic class
public class GenericDAOAndModelClass<T> {
    public static List<T> getAll(String table) { your code};
    public static T getOne(String table) { your other code };

}

public class User extends GenericDAOAndModelClass<User> {
    user methods and fields

}
```

and then you can call it like

```
List<User> userList = User.getAll("user");

User u = User.getOne("user");
```

You could put a static field in in every class extending GenericDAOAndModelClass to represent table name, so that you don't have to pass the parameter to getAll and getOne.

Comment: I don't really need it, I'm just looking at the cleanest and best OO-solution. Thanks, could you explain how to do this in the following situation: public static Object getOne(String table)?

Comment: The cleanest (imo) solution would be to have separate model and DAO classes.

Answer (score 1):

A collection of objects that implement different interfaces, IMO, runs counter to a reasonable design. A completely generic implementation will force you to re-implement pseudo-OOP functionality using `instanceof` etc.

Underlying DAOs can be templated to reduce boilerplate.

For example, [Hibernate DAOs are very often genericized](http://gochev.blogspot.com/2009/08/hibernate-generic-dao.html). The types they're *returning* is where type-specific functionality belongs.

Comment: Much thanks. I've been working with layers including service, transaction and dao in the past. It is just the first time I encounter this type issue. I'll look into 'Generic' now. Thank's for showing me the way!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create a DAO for every entity in my app. I think it is a cleaner and better design.

Comment: Could you motivate me why? If you have six functions in six different classes basically doing the same, that's major duplication? Isn't it better then to just make an abstraction?

Comment: @Kim It is--but not everything is the same. The DAO layer can be templated, but the functionality of each type *returned* by the DAO can't be, unless they all implement the exact same functionality. Which they don't.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have getObjects, saveOrUpdateObjects, getObject and deletObject. For example the class User and the class Item both need to do those functions with the same implementation, other particular functions are added in a subclass, like the function 'login(string,string)' in the class User. It looks sick to me to rewrite the function getObject to getUser if it has the same implementation as getObject, with one difference, the return type.

Comment: @Kim That's why there's templates: it's not the DAO that changes based on type, it's the *type* that changes. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: You might not need those different classes now, but your requirements might change. What if you are interested about Users who registered between certain dates? Then you create another method to solve this, but where do you put it? When you are using a DAO layer this is easy and everyone understands it.